# Remove selected user definitions from autocompletion

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to remove selected user definitions from autocompletion list?
E.g. several variables are defined with similar names:

```
var$tmp1 = 1 ;
var$tmp2 = 2 ;
var = 3 ;
```

But only `var` is used intensively.
Can `var$tmp1` and `var$tmp2` be removed from autocompletion?